A section of code runs much faster in Conda environment, Why?
I was running this section of code in a a basic venv (python 3.9):
if collection.count() == 0:
    collection.add(
    documents=documents, 
    metadatas=metadatas,
    ids=ids
)

and it took about 11 minutes to execute. For reasons we needed to deploy it on a Conda environment (python 3.10) and the same code on the same machine only took 4 minutes to execute. Is there a specific reason for this? The package I am using is chromaDB and this section of code is creating a vector database.
Machine:
Mac Pro
M1 pro
32gb
I looked at the version differences and I am aware of faster memory management etc but this doesn't feel like a full explanation of the speed increase.

you are asking to debug a black box. Try running some profiler and maybe there is a difference.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Generally speaking, Python 3.9 and 3.10 have major differences, since Python 3.10 uses Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler (if you use the PyPy interpreter) that speedups translating Python bytecode into machine code at runtime. Moreover, Conda environment has its own optimizations, specially in dependency management which affect speedups heavily.
BUT your main approach to find the root of the difference should be using a profiler tool. This can be an example:
import cProfile
profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.enable()

if collection.count() == 0:
    collection.add(
    documents=documents, 
    metadatas=metadatas,
    ids=ids
)

profiler.disable()
profiler.print_stats()


Could you elaborate? I'm aware of huge JIT works for python 3.13 (PEP744), but never heard of JIT in 3.10...

@STerliakov. JIT has been built-in since python 3.10 while using PyPy interpreter.

Oh, well, the question is not tagged [tag:pypy], I didn't even think about other implementation. Please mention PyPy explicitly in your answer, it might be misleading as currently written.

@Peyman.H Thanks for the help.I did this and compared and obviously i saw speed difference but nothing i could narrow down to versions or JIT. I went back and tried multiple version of python across across both virtual environments and Conda was alway faster. So narrowed it down a bit.
